# Can't find libjvm.so

Tags: java, c++

I have a program that uses voce.h which in turn uses jvm.

I have included all the necessary java files and have linked to the libjvm.so so I now doesn't get the compiler errors however when I run the program I get the error message:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried the part with export LD_LIBRARY_PATH without success.

```
The link to libjvm.so
/usr/java/jre1.8.0_65/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
The path to include files
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_65/include
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_65/include/linux
```

I use code::blocks as IDE.

Comment: What exactly did you put in LD_LIBRARY_PATH and have you exported it?

Comment: I put export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$JAVA_HOME/jre1.8.0_65/lib/amd64

Comment: I assume your program is compiled as 64-bit?

Comment: Didn't you forget the `server` parth of the path?

Answer (score 5):

If you already export some path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, just log off and then log in to clear it's cache, then just use the following command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_65/lib/amd64/server/
```

It should solve your problem.

Comment: @olof did you find any solution?